# "Tag Times in (l\ proc)[l_] is Protected"

Tags: programming

I am new in Mathematica. I would like to define a function which combine like terms in a list.

When the input is

`{{1,c[1,1],c[1,2]},{8/3,c[1,2],c[2,2]},{1,c[1,1],c[1,2]}}`,

the function returns `{{2,c[1,1],c[1,2]},{8/3,c[1,2],c[2,2]}}`.

I define the function in Mathematica as follows.

```
combineLikeTerms3[l_] := (

   r = List[];

   l2 = l;

   temp2 = List[];

   For[i = 1, i <= Length[l2], i++,

    If[MemberQ[temp2, Delete[l2[[i]], 1]] == False, (t = 0;

      For [j = 1, j <= Length[l2], j++,

       If[Delete[l2[[j]], 1] == Delete[l2[[i]], 1], 

         t = t + l2[[j]][[1]] ];

       ];

      s = l2[[i]];

      s[[1]] = Simplify[Expand[t]];

      r = Append[r, s];

      temp2 = Append[temp2, Delete[l2[[i]], 1]];

      )]

    ];

   Return[r]);
```

But there is an error:

> Tag Times in (l\ proc)[l_] is Protected

I don't know why. I didn't use the function Times.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try the whole thing again in a fresh *Mathematica* session. You are using so many variables, it is likely you forgot that you used `combineLikeTerms3` previously and tried to redefine it as a function.

Comment: @J.M., thank you very much. Yes, it is the problem you said. After I use the command Clear[combineLikeTerms3], everything is OK.